# Incomplete Output with LLM with max_new_tokens

Tags: machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, huggingface, large-language-model

I am experimenting with Huggingface LLM models.

And one issue I noticed is that output of the model ends abruptly and I ideally want it to complete the paragraph/sentences/code which it was it between of. (or altogether try to complete the answer within some fixed num of tokens)

Although I have provided max_new_tokens = 300 and also in prompt I write:
"Output should be maximum of 300 words."

The response is always incomplete and ends abruptly. Any way I can ask for a complete output within desired number of output tokens?

Code:

```
checkpoint = "HuggingFaceH4/starchat-alpha"
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu" 
class StarCoderModel:
  def __init__(self):
    self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
    # make sure `--gpus all` is provided in docker run command if gpu is required
    self.model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint, device_map='auto')

  def infer(self, input_text, token_count):
    inputs = self.tokenizer.encode(input_text, return_tensors="pt").to(device)
    outputs = self.model.generate(inputs,  max_new_tokens=token_count, pad_token_id=self.tokenizer.eos_token_id)
    return self.tokenizer.decode(outputs[0])[len(input_text):]
```

Sample-Output:

```
private DataType FuntionName(String someId) {
    // TODO: Replace with implementation that utilizes someId to obtain information
    return DataType.Value;
}


The comment:

- If someId is present in the code, use the getAPI from Client with someId as a parameter to obtain some information.
- If the
```

Comment: What's the length of your prompt? You have 2 limits: the +300 tokens that you give in arguments (useless in the prompt afaik) and the max context length of your model, which includes your prompt + answer: can you estimate your total size prompt + answer?

Comment: The other option is that the model is generated an "eos" token, which stops the generation. But this is very unlikely given that it occurs mid-sentence, so I rather think it's due to prompt length?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know when working with basic model like the one you mentioned there are chances that the model won't be able to give quite good results. You can switch to working with models like GPT-3 and llama if that's feasible.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35383687)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).